# beginDelayedTransition setting the X translation of child nodes not producing the required animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

We can use the Translate animation to produce the sliding animation like:

```
TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,100 );
moveAnim.setDuration(1000);
q.startAnimation(enterAnim);
```

Not able to reproduce similar effect using the Transition manager beginDelayedTransition.

```
com.transitionseverywhere.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(((ViewGroup)q.getParent()));
q.setTranslationX(q.setTranslationX+100);
```

With this we would be able to translate all the children

Comment: i know `android.transition.TransitionManager`, it is in the SDK, but have no idea what `com.transitionseverywhere.TransitionManager` is...

Comment: com.transitionseverywhere.TransitionManager is for supporting android.transition.TransitionManager from android 2.1

Comment: @pskink if we use android.transition.TransitionManager will the above work?

Comment: why dont you just use `ObjectAnimator` or better yet `ViewPropertyAnimator` ?

Comment: I think this will be sufficient for my use case. Let me try it..

Answer (score -1):

Two years too late, but in case anyone else needs this:

`TranslateAnimation` and other animation subclasses aren't intended to be used with `TransitionManager`. You want to just supply the type of animations you want the manager to use and then just do the translation:

```
Transition transition = new ChangeBounds().setDuration(1000);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.fragmentMyVideosRoot, transition);
q.setTranslationX(100);
```

That's it! You can use a `TransitionSet` to combine different types of transitions.

Comment: doesn't work for me(